# Adding an `asp:requiredfieldvalidator` for both required input and string length in HTML

Tags: asp.net

How do I add an `asp:requiredfieldvalidator` for both required input and string length in HTML?

I.e. Username is required and must be no longer than 40 characters.

Comment: you can use MaxLength property on textbox

Comment: asp:RequiredFieldValidator is not an HTML concept.  It is an ASP.Net concept.  Are you looking to implement it in ASP.Net or are you looking to use the HTML equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cand try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{0,40}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Maximum 40 characters allowed."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**EDIT**

You can add regular `RegularExpressionValidator` to your `RegularExpressionValidator` like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{0,40}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Maximum 40 characters allowed.">

</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" controltovalidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I already have a validation to make sure there is input. Can I add the above validation to that?  if so how?

Comment: @Kendramom You replace your validation with that